# How to define table cell height (CSS/HTML)

Tags: php, html, css

I'm using standard CSS/HTML for designing my website. Using a table for the navigation, I assign my `"#nav table"` with a width of `100%` and my `"#nav th"` with a height of `50px`.

My issue is that it's not actually setting itself to what I define. I had assumed it was as easy as just saying `height: 50px` but even when I define it as `0px` it remains at `90.5px.` In the HTML I did define my cells and what the table was, etc.

How can I fix this? Right now my site header is outrageously large because my table cells won't adjust to what I define them.

Using just PHP, HTML, and CSS.

CSS:

```
    #nav table {
        margin: 15px;
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        }

    #nav th {
        height: 0px;
        border: 5px black solid;
        padding: 25px;
        text-align: center;
        white-space: nowrap;
        letter-spacing: 0px;
        word-spacing: 5px;
        }
```

HTML:

```html
    <center>
    <table id="nav">
    <tr>
    <th><a href="LINK"><h1>LINK</h1></a></th>
    <th><a href="LINK1"><h1>LINK1</h1></a></th>
    <th><a href="LINK2"><h1>LINK2</h1></a></th>
    <th><a href="LINK3"><h1>LINK3</h1></a></th>
    <th><a href="LINK4"><h1>LINK4</h1></a></th>
    <th><a href="LINK5><h1>LINK5</h1></a></th>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </center>
    <p>
    Page Directory:
```

Comment: post your code, for both your table and your css we cant guess at it.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Yea, here you go (I forgot how to properly post code here but here it is anyways:)

CSS:

Comment: @user3399963 ...Where is the code?

Comment: You haven't closed your quote on `LINK5`.

Answer (score 1):

Using the code `#nav table` assumes an element with the ID "nav" with a table inside, and not a `table` element with the id "nav".

```
<style type="text/css">
  /* For a table with the id of 'nav'.  You could equally remove 'table'. */
  table#nav {
    margin: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
  }
  #nav th {
    height: 0px;
    border: 5px black solid;
    padding:0 25px;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    word-spacing: 5px;
  }
  th h1 {
    margin:0;
  }
</style>

<center>
  <table id="nav">
    <tr>
      <th><a href="LINK"><h1>LINK</h1></a></th>
      <th><a href="LINK1"><h1>LINK1</h1></a></th>
      <th><a href="LINK2"><h1>LINK2</h1></a></th>
      <th><a href="LINK3"><h1>LINK3</h1></a></th>
      <th><a href="LINK4"><h1>LINK4</h1></a></th>
      <!-- Don't forget to close all hrefs with a double-quote: -->
      <th><a href="LINK5"><h1>LINK5</h1></a></th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</center>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cz1o8a2n/1/

Note that if you have an element inside of your `th` that is 90.5px tall, you will not be able to make the table header less tall using CSS (unless you use CSS to decrease the height of that element).

**Edit**: Consider using the more moder `nav` instead, with list-items.  Plus, you'll have an easier time making your site responsive if you like.  :)

```
<style type="text/css">
  nav {
    margin: 15px;
    width: calc(100% - 30px);
    position: fixed;
    text-align:center;
  }
  nav ul {
    padding-left:0;
    list-style:none;
  }
  nav li {
    display:inline-block;
    border: 3px black solid;
    padding:0 20px;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    word-spacing: 5px;
    margin:2px 0;
  }
</style>
<nav id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="LINK">LINK</a></li>
    <li><a href="LINK1">LINK1</a></li>
    <li><a href="LINK2">LINK2</a></li>
    <li><a href="LINK3">LINK3</a></li>
    <li><a href="LINK4">LINK4</a></li>
    <li><a href="LINK5">LINK5</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cz1o8a2n/2/

Comment: The odd part was that as least I had thought I was doing that. For whatever reason, even when I define the attribute #nav th to a height of 50px, it decides it's going to put in 90.5px anyways. My font isn't even that large (like 18-20px or something) so I couldn't understand why it was just defining it's own height and actually overlooking what I was inputting. Been trying to fix it for the good part of an hour.

Comment: You have a lot of padding on the `th` (25px all around), plus the `h1` tag comes with a margin-top and margin-bottom.

Comment: Actually I'm a little confused on your response. So a #nav table is a table called #nav, right? This is what I was intending to use. I didn't want to call any pre-built nav objects when I did this.

Comment: Sorry - I jumped the gun.  I figured you were using the HTML5 "nav" tag.  You are correct about `#nav` being sufficient to target a table with the ID of "nav".  Here's how to remove the margin on H1's inside all table headers:  https://jsfiddle.net/cz1o8a2n/1/

Comment: Ok, just uploaded my new style.css document without the margins or paddings on the table or table cells, but it's still reading that the table cells are 90.5px. Overall it shrunk, but the cells are still too large for the look I'm going for.

Comment: Do you still have margins on your `h1`s?  Also, you might want to use a different tag if SEO is of consideration.  That many H1's on one page is, as I understand, a bad idea.  Perhaps H2's?

Comment: Is there perhaps another way of doing this that looks neat and modern? I'm actually trying this table thing as a new way of designing my navigation header bar. Before, I was using two images that were identical but the color of the font so that when I set the transition on the hover it eased into the brighter font. I'm still doing the same thing, but with nearly less than half the CSS document before for easy updates. If this is just an issue with tables and cells maybe I should try to find a different way to host a 6-column navigation that looks good.

Comment: I never had margins on my H1's. Are those pre-built in?

Comment: Yes, margins on headers and paragraphs are pre-built in (in all the browsers I am aware of).  Check my new Fiddle link in my answer to see how to force remove the excess margin.

Comment: It was indeed a pre-built margin thing on the H1. I just set that to zero and now it's at 57px cell height. I would like to get cell height to 30px but if that's not possible that can be liveable.

Comment: Would it be OK to reduce the font-size on the H1's, or the border around the th's?  That will decrease the height of the table header.

Comment: As for your question about a neat and modern way, I would recommend the `nav` tag.  Here's an example of how I would use it: https://jsfiddle.net/cz1o8a2n/2/  If you don't like it "floating" onto the next line as your screen gets less wide, you could put a `min-width` on the nav (try 600px in my Fiddle example).

Comment: Thanks, I like the list idea a lot more. Looks a lot more ready off the bat on looking good. Thanks very much!

Comment: Great to hear that.  I edit that part into my answer to accommodate.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**
You're missing a `"` for LINK5.

```
<center>
    <table id="nav">
        <tr>
            <th><a href="LINK"><h1>LINK</h1></a></th>
            <th><a href="LINK1"><h1>LINK1</h1></a></th>
            <th><a href="LINK2"><h1>LINK2</h1></a></th>
            <th><a href="LINK3"><h1>LINK3</h1></a></th>
            <th><a href="LINK4"><h1>LINK4</h1></a></th>
            <th><a href="LINK5"><h1>LINK5</h1></a></th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</center>
```

**CSS**
If you want to apply css to a table with the id set to **nav** your selector needs to be `table#nav`. As for the table headings being larger than you like, the issue is the h1 tag inherently has a pretty big margin. This big margin is making your table headings larger than you'd like.

```
table#nav {
    margin: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}

#nav th {
    height: 50px;
    border: 5px black solid;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#nav th h1 {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Just used this, but it's still showing the cell height as 57px and not 50px. I'm starting to wonder if it's something to do with my hosting site.